# How to fix my problem with missing modules when converting .py to .exe with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, pyinstaller

I started scraping in Python using **Scrapy** in PyCharm few weeks ago. I found out about **PyInstaller**, which I used to make executable. The problem is that whenever I run .exe file, it opens and closes instantly.

I found out that I get a lot of warnings when creating .exe like this ones bellow:

> 5666 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency
>   of
>   c:\users\luka-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
>   5756 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
>   dependency of
>   c:\users\luka-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
>   8482 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>   dependency of
>   c:\users\luka-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs_hashlib.pyd
>   8576 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
>   dependency of
>   c:\users\luka-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs\select.pyd
>   8684 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency
>   of
>   c:\users\luka-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs_bz2.pyd

Running .exe file through Command Prompt says that the Scrapy module is missing, tried to fix it by adding --paths parameter to PyInstaller command when creating .exe but didn't work. I already tried reinstalling pyinstaller but no effects.

I'd like to be able to run scraper from my PC and on other PC-s also.

Comment: Does your .exe output have lines like `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '...\\scrapy\\VERSION'` or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named...`?

Comment: @Georgiy Thank you for reply. Here is the output:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy'
[8476] Failed to execute script kpspider

Comment: How did you install scrapy (usin pip, anaconda python distibution or something else)?
Did you create a new python environment for this?
According to your warning messages You tried to run py installer on default python environment.

Comment: @Georgiy I'm using PyCharm for developing, so I added package through PyCharm. And one thing I noticed is that my libraries and scripts are found in "venv" folder, while my scraper is in other. I guess that "venv" stands for Virtual Environment?
No, I didn't create new environment.

Answer (score 0):

if it works on your IDE then try to pack script to single package using below command

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

It will include all the required libraries in the package. Also update the libraries which available on machine, that will help you to include missing files/dll's

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but still it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Try to use Terminal which is available in Pycharm. The error seems to be, you are using modules which are installed in **venv** but you are trying to convert to **.exe** using system interpreter